# Xcode unable to build ipa after enabling app groups feature

Tags: xcode, ios-app-group

I'm trying to build an enterprise distribution ipa file using xCode. Was able to build it successfully.

However, when I turn on the App Groups feature in the capabilities tab. I'm hitting

Permissions failure, your account does not have have permission to create iOS Distribution certificate.

I'm currently using XCode Version 8.3.1 (8E1000a).

[image]

**Update:**

Able to build using app group name which is similar to the app bundle id
(group.com.xx.appgroupPrototype and com.xx.appgroupPrototype)

However, after adding a new app group (e.g. group.com.xx.appgroupPrototype.sandbox), the permission failure error will occur when building IPA.

**Question:**

From the above finding, does it mean

1) App Group name must be similar to the app bundle id

2) We can't add a new app group name